# optaplnner score which contraints are not satisfied

Tags: java, drools, optaplanner

I am exploring optaplanner,i found that it gives me one best solution along with some score value like -4Hard/-3hard.

I want to get more information regarding this score like list the hard and soft constraints which was not satisfied in given solution,so that user is able to change the constraints slightly to get even better solution.

Is it possible in optaplanner and if yes, how?

Comment: Yes, see docs section [Explaining the score](http://docs.jboss.org/drools/release/latest/optaplanner-docs/html_single/index.html#explainingTheScore).

Comment: @GeoffreyDeSmet, its all about how to calculate score value,i didn't find any section which is specifying about unsatisfied constraints information,can you point out some example?

Comment: Why doesn't the section "5.5. Explaining the score: using score calculation outside the Solver" suffice?

Answer (score 0):

Your hard/soft scores are depending from your implementation.

Take *CloudBalancingEasyScoreCalculator* ([see docs](http://docs.jboss.org/drools/release/6.1.0.Final/optaplanner-docs/html_single/index.html#d0e901)) from examples in Optaplanner.
You see that scores are in fact cumulated sums. 
Optaplanner has no chance to know the detail of each constraint considered within that sum.
Nowhere a set of constraints is defined. We just gather them as a global objective.

**Solution 1** : In such case, solution is to track yourself unrespected constraints when computing your score.

On same example, you would insert this processing here:

```
        // Hard constraints

        int cpuPowerAvailable = computer.getCpuPower() - cpuPowerUsage;

        if (cpuPowerAvailable < 0) {

            hardScore += cpuPowerAvailable;

            cloudbalance.trackUnrespectedHardConstraint(...)


        }
```

instead of

```
        // Hard constraints

        int cpuPowerAvailable = computer.getCpuPower() - cpuPowerUsage;

        if (cpuPowerAvailable < 0) {

            hardScore += cpuPowerAvailable;

        }
```

I didn't explore Drools score configuration that may be a **solution 2** for your need.

Hope this helps.

[ThePolyscope.com](http://ThePolyscope.com)